# passing array to view codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the problem of doing the validation of fields myself. Now there are 5-6 fields in the form. So I am checking each one in my controller, and if there is wrong i wish to load the view again and pass the error array to it.

I achieved the above functionality with this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>

</head>
<body>


<?php
    echo $fullname;
?>

<?
 echo form_open('/membership/register');    
?>


<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="text" name="cpassword" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Mobile</h5>
<input type="text" name="mobile" value="" size="15" />

<h5>Home</h5>
<input type="text" name="home" value="" size="15" />

<h5>Full Name</h5>
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="" size="100" />
<br><br>
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and in controller the code is:

```
            if (preg_match('#[0-9]#',$fullname))
            { 
                $errors['fullname'] = 'wrong name format!';
                $this->load->view('register', $errors); 
            }
```

Now the real problem I have is if the many fields are wrong. I want to have $errors array passed to view and accessed there for all the values it contains. so I don't have to specify $fullname or $mobile to get the value. How can this be done? as to show the user everything missing in one go

Answer (score 3):

First of all I advise using codeigniter's built in form validation class

Here is how I usually process my validation in the controller:

```
if ($this->input->post()) 
{
    // process the POST data and store accordingly
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|xss_clean');
    // the rest of your form fields validation can be set here
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // validation hasnt run or has errors, here just call your view
        $this->load->view('same_view_file_with_the_form', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        // process the POST data upon correct validation
    }
}
```

In my view file I call each error like this:

```
<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />
<span class="error-red"><?php echo form_error("username"); ?></span>
<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />
<span class="error-red"><?php echo form_error("password"); ?></span>
<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="text" name="cpassword" value="" size="50" />
<span class="error-red"><?php echo form_error("cpassword"); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do all your checks in the controller prior to binding `errors` into the view.

e.g.

```
$errors = array();

if (preg_match('#[0-9]#',$fullname))
{ 
    $errors['fullname'] = 'wrong name format!';
}

if ( do_something_to_validate(mobile) )
{
    $errors['mobile'] = 'invalid mobile';
}

// after checking everything do this
$this->load->view('register', $errors);
```